# Integral / integrand in south korean series I'm Not a Robot

Tags: integration, popular-math

From Mystery Recapped recap of part1 of South Korean series [I'm Not a Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_Not_a_Robot) (video is [Man Is Allergic To Human Touch, So Spends $1M On Female Robot; Turns Out She's Human In Disguise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCBX38fdsp4))

[image]

It looks like

$$p(r)=\frac{4}{a_0^3}r^2e^{\frac{-2r}{a_0}}, r \ge 0$$

and has some antiderivative

$$P(r) = \int_0^r \frac{4}{a_0^3}s^2e^{\frac{-2}{a_0}}, r \ge 0$$

1. Is the integrand missing an $s$? I think it's supposed to be

$$P(r) = \int_0^r \frac{4}{a_0^3}s^2e^{\frac{-2s}{a_0}}, r \ge 0$$

2. Btw the way to integrate $\int x^2 e^{-x} dx$ is like double integration by parts with $u=x$ and $dv = xe^{-x} dx$?

Comment: Yes, almost certainly a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it's a typo.
2. No need. It's just $u=x^2$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%5E2+e%5E%28-x%29+dx

I was thinking of something else namely $\int(2x^2+1)e^{x^2}dx$